# Error C3083 in unordered_set.hpp?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a relatively big project (in VS2010) using boost. For some reason which I can't pin down to a simple code example I am hitting an error from within the library:

```
boost_1_53_0\boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp(56): error C3083: 'detail': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
boost_1_53_0\boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp(505) : see reference to class template instantiation 'anydsl::boost::unordered::unordered_set<T,H,P,A>' being compiled
```

The problem probably originates from somewhere else but the compiler gives absolutely no hint about its origin.

Any ideas where it could be originating from?

Anyone else experienced a similar problem?

I upgraded my boost 1.47.0 to 1.53.0 after hitting the bug but the problem persists.

Comment: Could you test including unordered_set before any other files?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried that, but the problem persists.

Comment: Strike that. It actually fixes the problem in the .cpp file I do that, but resurfaces itself in another. It gives me a good hint on what is going on :)

Comment: Why do you have `anydsl::` prefix?
have you wrapped your header inclusion in namespace?

Comment: That wrapping should not happen. Somehow I missed that from the error message!

Comment: write an answer to your question =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by `kassak`, the error message suggests that you are including `unordered_set.hpp` while you are within another namespace of your own. Never ever do that as bad things happen.

In your particular case, the compiler tries to resolve

```
typedef boost::unordered::detail::set<A, T, H, P> types;
```

within your namespace `anydsl`. As `anydsl::boost::unordered::detail` does not exist, it throws a (somewhat misleading) error that `detail` does not name a type.